# How Recaptcha Detect Fake User-Agent

Tags: javascript, google, captcha

I'm trying to understand how can [recaptcha__en.js](https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1557729121476/recaptcha__en.js) detect fake User-Agent, for the test you can try the [demo here](https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v3-request-scores.php) with addon User-Agent switcher  installed, for logged in user it will get score `0.9` no matter what is The UA but here here `Score` I get without logged in:

1. Fresh Old firefox 46, Original UA: `0.3 - 0.7`
2. Updated browser with Original UA: `0.3 - 0.7`
3. Updated browser with spoofed UA: `0.1`

As you can see even with updated browser but If I change the UA it will get score `0.1` or marked as `bot/spam`, so is there other way to detect user-agent other than javascript variable `navigator` or how can recaptcha detect fake UA?

Answer (score 4):

Certain browsers have certain features. The service runs JavaScript they provide you, so they can run a lot of feature tests in the actual browser. This can be used to validate your userAgent string.

For example (purely hypothetical), if everyone knows that Chrome after v50 supports CSS variables, and any Chrome after v40 no longer support the old vibration API, but your browser claims to be v55 and seems to support both features, you're busted. A quick visit to https://caniuse.com/ offers numerous "smoking guns" one could use to detect such version/feature correlation.

There's also a lot of web APIs that only one or another browser supports, like [-ms-browse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-browse) CSS and microsoft browsers. This is basically the reverse of the web developer advice "don't browser detect, feature detect for forward compatibility". By doing both, recaptha can spot liars, unless you're so good at spoofing (altering JS and DOM internals along the way) that you might as well be using the browser you are pretending to be, and at that point it can't/won't care.